# Extend() is not working when used inside Print()

Tags: python, list, extends

```
Marks = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Students = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
print(Students)
```

1. Students.extend(Marks)
   print(Students)
2. print(Students.extend(Marks))

1 is working but not 2.

Comment: Because extend() doesnt return anything

Answer (score 1):

The Python List `extend()` method doesnt return anything, therefore there is nothing to print

See the documentation here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm